# NSOperationQueue finished wont start new method

Tags: objective-c, methods, selector, nsoperation, nsoperationqueue

When my observer tells me that there are no more operations, function is not called (performSelector...). Funny thing is that NSLog(@"queue has completed") is logged correctly.

```
- (void) observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object
                     change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context
{
if (object == self.operationQueue && [keyPath isEqualToString:@"operations"]) {
    if ([self.operationQueue.operations count] == 0)
    {
        [self performSelector:@selector(refreshCollectionView) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.2];
        // Do something here when your queue has completed
        NSLog(@"queue has completed");

    }
}
else {
    [super observeValueForKeyPath:keyPath ofObject:object
                           change:change context:context];
}
}
```

EDIT

Got it:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
             [self performSelector:@selector(refreshCollectionView) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.2];
             });
```

Dunno why performSelectorOnMainThread... didnt work but it works this way.

Answer (score 1):

If your observer is being fired on the same thread as the queue, it is quite likely that the queue's thread is being reaped upon completion.   Since -performSelector:...afterDelay: requires a running run loop, it is likely dropped on the floor.

Since you are updating the UI anyway, perform that selector on the main thread.

Comment: got it but doesnt work anyway :/ any method wont start (even if I put stuff from refreshCollectionView inside queue complete statement)